# active job with rails rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-activejob

I have installed a gem `rspec-rails`. Everything is working fine except `ActiveJob`.
I have tried to implement the `ActiveJob` in RSpec with:

```
include ActiveJob::TestHelper
```

and here's the code for the RSsec Job Controller:

```
describe "#perform_later" do
  it "Send Invoice Reminder" do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    InvoiceReminderJob.perform_later
    expect(InvoiceReminderJob).to have_enqueued_job
  end
end
```

`spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe InvoiceReminderJob, type: :job do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper
  # pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"

  describe "#perform_later" do
    it "Send Invoice Reminder" do
      ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
      InvoiceReminderJob.perform("test")
      expect(InvoiceReminderJob).to have_enqueued_job
    end
  end
end
```

`invoice_reminder_job_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe InvoiceReminderJob, type: :job do
  # include ActiveJob::TestHelper
  # pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"

  describe "#perform_later" do
    it "Send Invoice Reminder" do
      ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
      InvoiceReminderJob.perform_later
      expect(InvoiceReminderJob).to have_enqueued_job
    end
  end
end
```

When I am trying to run rspec with the command `rspec` I am getting the following error:

> uninitialized constant ActiveJob (NameError)

Here is my `Gemfile`:

Here is the gemfile included for my project:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4'
gem 'acts_as_tenant'
gem 'audited', '~> 4.0'
gem 'audited-activerecord'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.6'
gem 'axlsx'
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-generators'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bullet', group: 'development'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem 'clockwork'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'devise'
gem 'eefgilm'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'i18n-js', '>= 3.0.0.rc11'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'mailman'
gem 'net-ssh'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
gem 'rails-console-tweaks'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'rails_best_practices'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'roo'
gem 'roo-google'
gem 'roo-xls'
gem 'rubocop', require: false
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'seed_dump'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'traceroute'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'zip'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'rails-erd'
  gem 'capistrano-rails-console', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-maintenance', '~> 1.0', require: false
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'simplecov'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'activejob'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```

And here is the output of `bundle show activejob`:

```
/Users/221/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activejob-0
```

I have tried to search with lots of solution but I am not able to resolve this issue. If anyone could help me with it, I would be really grateful.

Comment: 1. `activejob` is a dependency for the main application, *including production environment*. You should not place the gem in the `:development` and `:test` groups, but rather install it in all environments (i.e. outside the block).

Comment: 2. I don't understand why you're writing (the same!) tests in `spec_helper.rb`. That file is, by its very name, supposed to contain *helpers*, not tests. And certainly not duplicate tests. Are you even `require`ing that file anywhere?

Comment: 3. Even with that said, I don't understand why you'd get a *"uninitialized constant `ActiveJob`"* error. Can you try running `bundle exec rspec`, and show the **full** error, if it persists?

Comment: It's not `ActiveJob::TestHelper` its `ActiveJobHelpers`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using rails 4.1.5, ActiveJob is introduced in rails 4.2

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by using the gem "gem 'activejob_backport'