# NoMethodError: undefined method `enqueue' | RSpec | ActiveJob | Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, delayed-job, rails-activejob

> Using Rails `4.1.6`, Ruby `2.3.1`.

I followed this guide to [use ActiveJob in Rails 4.1](https://kinopyo.com/en/blog/use-activejob-in-rails-4-1)

```rb
# app/jobs/my_notification_job.rb

 class MyNotificationJob < ActiveJob::Base
   queue_as :default

   def perform(args)
     ...
   end
 end





# my_model.rb

 def send_notification
   ...
   MyNotificationJob.enqueue({key1: val1, key2: val2})
   ...
 end





# my_models_controller.rb
 
 def publish
   ...
   my_model_instance.send_notification
   ...
 end
```

But it was throwing following load error in test env

```
LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- active_job/arguments
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
# /gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
```

so I skipped loading ActiveJob in test env

```rb
# config/initializers/active_job.rb

unless Rails.env.test?
  require 'active_job'
  
  ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
end
```

and based on [dhruv mehta's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6708849/dhruv-mehta) suggestion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720063/active-job-with-rails-rspec) I added gem `activejob_backport` in test group

```rb
# Gemfile

group :test  do

  gem 'activejob_backport'

  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.9'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.11.1'
  gem 'faker', '~> 2.2.1'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers'
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

## RSpec Code

```rb
# spec/rails_helper.rb
 
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper
 end





# spec/my_models_controller_spec.rb
 
 require 'rails_helper'

 RSpec.describe MyModelsController, type: :controller do
   it 'enqueues the job' do
     ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
     get :publish
   end
 end
```

But then I was getting following error

```rb
NoMethodError: undefined method `enqueue' for MyNotificationJob:Class
```

After looking into the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Enqueuing.html#method-i-enqueue), I realised `enqueue` must be called upon an instance. But as you can see above I am calling it on `MyNotificationJob` class and it works fine in production.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this

Comment: what is `MyNotificationJob` please add related information ?

Comment: it inherits from `ActiveJob::Base` and will send an email notification

Answer (score 0):

leaving aside the issue of class method / instance method, I would be inclined to mock `MyNotificationJob` something like this.

```
before do
  allow(MyNotificationJob).to receive(:enqueue).and_return(true) # or whatever value is appropriate
end
```